# Is this proof that every convergent sequence is bounded correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, proof-verification

I've tried the following proof that a convergent sequence is bounded but I'm not sure if it is correct or not.

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and suppose $(x_k)$ is a sequence of points of $M$ that converges to $a \in M$. Since the sequence is convergent, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $k_0$ such that if $k > k_0$ then $x_k \in B(a;\varepsilon)$. In that case, there is a finite number of points of the sequence, namely $\{x_{1},\dots,x_{k_0} \}$ that can be still outside of the ball. In that case, consider $r = \max\{d(a,x_i) : 1 \leq i \leq k_0\}+1$, then I claim that for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x_k \in B(a;r+\varepsilon)$. In truth, first it's obvious that $B(a;\varepsilon)\subset B(a;r+\varepsilon)$ because if $y \in B(a;\varepsilon)$ then $d(y,a) < \varepsilon < \varepsilon + r$ since $r > 0$. Also, by definition of $r$, we know that $\max\{d(a,x_i) : 1 \leq i \leq k_0\} < r < r+\varepsilon$ and so each $d(a,x_i) < r+\varepsilon$ so that $\{x_1, \dots, x_{k_0}\}\subset B(a;\varepsilon+r)$. Since the points $x_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq k_0$ are in the ball and the points $x_k$ for $k > k_0$ are in the ball, we conclude that every $x_k \in B(a;\varepsilon+r)$ and so the sequence is bounded.

Is this proof correct or there are any problems with it?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: It seems correct to me !

Comment: Is there anything about your proof you are particularly unsure about?

Comment: I was a little unsure about not specifying any $\varepsilon$. I know that $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary and I left it that way. Should I select one to do the proof? For instance, take $\varepsilon = 1$? Also, I was a little unsure on just summing $1$ to the maximum of the distances to make $r$ greater than every distance. It was something that I thought about like "it will work", but I was a little unsure if that's the usual way to proceed in cases like that.

Comment: Yes, take $\epsilon = 1$. That way, when you are choosing the max over a finite set, the finite set is not changing with your choice of $\epsilon$.

Comment: Choosing $\varepsilon$ certainly gives a nicer proof to look at.