# (Correct Proof?) Show that every convergent sequence $(\mathbf{x}_{k})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof

Now, this is a pretty simple proof and I just wanted some more experienced members here to have a look at it and maybe give me feedback on my proof idea for the statement in the title.

I also found another proof [in this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466555/is-this-proof-that-every-convergent-sequence-is-bounded-correct), which seems a lot more elaborate than mine. However, if my proof is correct too, of course I'd prefer to use my own instead of just copying someone else's. :)

So I do not necessarily need full answers. Some feedback and hints on how to improve my proof is more than enough.

This proof was "inspired" by a similar one for sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. I hope i didn't generalize in a way that is not possible.

Let  $(\mathbf{x}_{k})$ be a convergent series in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ that converges with limit $\mathbf{x}$. We then know, that for an arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$, we can find an index $N=N(\epsilon)$, s.t.
$$\lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_{k}\rVert < \epsilon \space \text{for all $k \geq N$}$$

From the reverse triangle inequality we then also know that
$$\lvert \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert - \lVert\mathbf{x}_{k}\rVert \rvert \leq \lVert\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_{k}\rVert < \epsilon$$

This implies that $\lVert\mathbf{x_{k}}\rVert < \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert + \epsilon$. Now there is only a finite number of elements (up to the index $N$), for which this does not *necessarily* hold.

So now let $M = \max\lbrace \lVert\mathbf{x}_{1}\rVert , \lVert\mathbf{x}_{2}\rVert, \dots, \lVert\mathbf{x}_{N-1}\rVert, \lVert\mathbf{x}_{N}\rVert, \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert + \epsilon \rbrace$. Then we have $\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert \leq M$ for all $\mathbf{x}_{k}$, and hence $(\mathbf{x}_{k})$ is bounded. $\square$

Since the other proof I mentioned at the beginning made use of the concept of *open balls* (which I felt was one of the most critical differences between sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ and in topological spaces), I wasn't sure if it's alright to use the same, rather simple, argument as in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thank you in advance for your help and your feedback! I hope I can learn something new. ;)

Comment: Proof seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x_n$ isn't bounded and for all $k\in\mathbb {N}$ exist a $x_{n_k}$ such that $\Vert x_{n_k} \Vert > k$.

Now, the subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k \in\mathbb {N}}$ of $x_n$ diverges, absurd because every subsequence must be converges to the same limit that $x_n$

Comment: Thank you. That really makes the proof shorter too.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof seems more than okay to me (in fact it is the most elegant elementary proof of the statement that I know of). Note that, in your proof, the only essential analytical property you used was the triangle equality, of which the so-called reverse triangle equality follows. Specific properties of $\mathbb{R}^n$ were never used! I don't know whether you are already familiar with abstract normed spaces, but basically, a normad space is any $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace or $\mathbb{C}$-vectorspace $A$ endorsed with some "norm"
$$
\lVert . \rVert : A \to [0, +\infty[
$$
i.e. a map which satisfies triangle equality, $\lVert r\mathbf{x}\rVert = \lvert r \rvert \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert$ for all $r \in \mathbb{R}$ ($\in \mathbb{C}$) and $\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert = 0$ if and only if $\mathbf{x} = 0$. There are many normed spaces that are not $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. because they have infinite dimension), and what you've actually proved is

> For any normed $\mathbb{R}$-vectorspace ($\mathbb{C}$-vectorspace) $A$, convergent sequences are bounded.

An example of an infinite-dimensional normed space is the vector space
$$
\mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})} = \lbrace (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N} \mid \#\lbrace i \in \mathbb{N} \mid x_i \neq 0 \rbrace < +\infty \rbrace
$$
with norm
$$
\lVert . \rVert : \mathbb{R}^{(\mathbb{N})} \to [0, +\infty[ : (x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mapsto \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \lvert x_i \rvert
$$

Comment: Wow thanks very much! Yeah I had learned about normed vector spaces in my introductory math class, which consisted mainly of linear algebra. Although I did not intend to generalize it this far, I'm happy to know that I'm on the right side. Also thanks for the additional explanations. I'm happy for any input that goes beyond what we cover in our classes.

Comment: And we're happy to provide it. ;-) If you have any further questions, be sure to let us know!